# Bootstrap button at bottom of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an iPhone app built with Bootstrap. One of the pages is a static text html page with a button at the bottom.

When the static text is too long for the screen, and the user scrolls up the page to see the rest of the text, the button scrolls up with the text and is not fixed to the bottom of the screen.

This is the html code at the end of the page

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 no-padding">        
    <button class="btn btn-block no-padding" 
        type="submit" ng-click="accept()" id="login-btn"> 
         {{"button.accept"}}
    </button>
</div>
```

How can I make the button stick to the bottom even if the page is scrolled up.

Comment: you may want to take a look at the sticky footer example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

You could build a new class for your button and give it an absolute position like:

```
.my-fixed-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

… not tested, should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you also would want the button centered. It also wouldn't be necessary to have the button inside of a div if it's going to be absolutely positioned. Also, because of `position: absolute`, I would use the `left` and `transform` properties I have set below in order to center it:

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

If you needed that div for whatever reason, then apply the above CSS to the div and **not** the button.